# How to find $f(2)+f^{-1}(5)$ if $f(2x^2+3x+4)=6x^2+9x+20$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

$$f(2x^2+3x+4)=6x^2+9x+20$$

How to solve $f(2)+f^{-1}(5)$ ?

Any help or advice on solving is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any assumption on $f$? e.g. is $f$ polynomial?

Comment: Do you know that this holds for every $x\in\mathbb R$? Or for every $x\in\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(2x^2+3x+4)=3(2x^2+3x+4)+8$$
So a simple conjecture is $f(x)=3x+8$. As $f(-1)=5,f(2)=14$; the expression to evaluate becomes $13$.